# hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering doesn't work on windows

Tags: windows, haskell

im trying to read raw characters from input but modifying the buffer mode to "NoBufferMode" doesn't seems to work the way i need, it still requires to press newline,

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    c <- getChar
    print c
```

i have seen solutions using foreing calls but that blocks threads

Answer (score 1):

With GHC 9.0.1 you can compile with `-rtsopts` and use the new `+RTS --io-manager=native` rts option when running your program. From the release notes:

> A new I/O manager (WinIO) is now available as a community technical preview which is designed to allow experimentation and bootstrapping of third-party packages such as Network. The new I/O manager is off by default and can be enabled with the RTS flag `--io-manager=native`. Currently the I/O manager is unoptimized and is focused more on correctness. There is also no support for pipes and sockets. These will be added in the next release. [*see more*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgNh5mdZ1xw).